# Change url data in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good, I'm starting to use php and codeigniter as framework, and I want to know if it is possible to modify the url, for example I have the following user controller and inside an edit method to edit the data of a user the url would look like this: http://localhost/sis/user/edit/2, I want to know if it is possible to hide the parameter that passed to the method of my controller

Comment: with .htaccess, it may be possible.

Comment: i think not possible how pass value in controller

Comment: instead of parameter, you can try slug..

Comment: Then it is possible to change it, by the name instead of showing the id?, that another option is left

Comment: why do you want to hide it?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it is not possible to hide the parameters that are passed to your controller if you're using them in your URL.

There are quite some fancy things that you can do with Codeigniter routing (https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html), but hiding parameters isn't one of them. If you want to 'hide' the parameter(s), you will have to use another way of passing these parameters. This can be, for instance, passing the parameters through a hidden field in your user edit form, like so:

```
<form action="http://localhost/sis/user/edit">
  <!-- Hidden input field that contains user id -->
  <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="2">

  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="submit" value="Edit user">
</form>
```

You can fetch your user ID in your controller like so: `$_POST['userid']`. Or the CodeIgniter way of using $_POST, `$this->input->post('userid')`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass parametre in hidden you need to add an input  hidden that has an id value (in your situation here 2) and then you can submit ur form